# Understanding the following definition of a relation on a set.

Tags: logic, set-theory, relations, first-order-logic

I am a little confused about the following definition in my Logic script.

> Definition: Let $k \geq 1$ and $A$ a set. Then:
>
> $1.$ $A^k$ is the set of all $k-$tuples of the elements from $A$.
>
> $2.$ A $k-$digit relation on $A$ is a subset of $A^k$.

In the first definition it says $k-$ tuples of the elements in $A$. Does this refer of many tuples there are in **total** in $A^k$ or how many elements are inside a **single tuple** in $A^k$. For example, let $k=2$ and $A = \{1,2,3\}$. Then would $A^k=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),...,(3,3)\}$ or would it be $A^k=\{(1,1),(3,2)\}$?

Furthermore, what does the $2$nd point mean?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to read a bit further and understand something from the context. Also, why would $A^2$ have two **pairs**, rather than two elements, or two sequences, etc.?

Comment: A *pair* is a two-tuple $(a,b)$. A k-tuple is made of k elements: $(a_1, \ldots, a_k)$. As written above, $A^k$ is the set of **all** k-tuples.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The script only has this definition and starts talking about the empty relation and other things. Which is why I asked here.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So a $k-$ tuple refers to how many elements are inside a tuple correct?

Comment: And it never comes back to any type of relations?

Comment: A *binary* relation is made of pairs, and thus is a subset of $A^2= A \times A$. A k-ary relation is made of k-uples, and thus is a subset of $A^k$. It is a subset because the relation $R \subseteq A^k$ does **not** necessarily contains all the tuples.

Comment: @AsafKaragila At least not for the next couple of pages, no.

Comment: Exactly: a *pair* has a pair of elements. A k-tuple has k elements.